# what the type mean in the ant build system

Tags: ant, nant

There is type definition like Path. Is this a special property in ANT?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [Path-like Structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)? Maybe that will answer your question.

Comment: I read, but still wonder what does this kind of struture mean? Is this special property?

Comment: Nope, it's type. You can use a property inside these type, but it is no special property. See [Apache Ant User Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)